# Aliases for Value Constructors

Tags: haskell, types, alias

Is it possible to define aliases for value constructors? The context is this: I am writing a program, that implements primitive recursive functions as Turing machines. For that I am working with unary integer encoding. My Turing machine type is defined like this:

```
-- definition of a Turing machine
data TuringMachine a = TuringMachine
                     State      -- q0
                     (Set State) -- F
                     (Set State) -- Q
                     (Set (Symbol a)) -- Gamma
                     (Set (Symbol a)) -- Sigma
                     (Map (State, Symbol a) (State, Symbol a, Instruction)) -- delta
                     deriving (Show)
```

where my symbol type is defined like this:

```
data Symbol a = Symbol a | Blank | Delim | Final | One deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

I have `One` as a convenience in there, so I don't need to write `Symbol 1` everywhere. But that is a little untidy. I would like to define an alias outside of the type `Symbol`, like

```
alias One = Symbol 1
```

and

```
alias Zero = Blank
```

Is something like that possible?

Comment: pattern synonyms may be what you want, but for what you're strictly asking about here you can just define `one = Symbol 1`, `zero = Blank`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{-# Language PatternSynonyms #-}

pattern Zero :: Symbol a
pattern Zero = Blank

pattern One :: (Eq a, Num a) => Symbol a
pattern One = Symbol 1
```

works (bidirectional pattern synonym)

Comment: Just to expand on this a bit, with a bidirectional pattern synonym, `One` is equivalent to `Symbol 1` *both* when used as a pattern (definition `func One = impl` = `func (Symbol 1) = impl`) *and* when used as a value constructor (call `func One` = `func (Symbol 1)`).

Comment: Can't get this to work. Always getting `Invalid type signature: pattern Zero :: ...
    Perhaps you meant to use PatternSynonyms?`. Why is that?

Comment: @Io tolmencre, pattern synonyms are not in the base Haskell language. They can be enabled in GHC with `{-# Language PatternSynonyms #-}` (a language pragma) at the top of the source file. A good editor will suggest and do this for you.

Comment: @heisenbug Oh thanks, I did not put that line at the very top of the file but just above the `pattern ...` stuff