# Haskell: "Qualified name in binding position" error with Map.empty

Tags: haskell, newtype, pattern-synonyms

I'm trying to create a pattern synonym for a newtype with an empty map.

```
{-# Language PatternSynonyms #-}

import qualified Data.Map as Map

newtype StoreEnv = StoreEnv (Map.Map Int String)
   deriving (Eq, Show)

pattern EmptyStore :: StoreEnv
pattern EmptyStore = StoreEnv Map.empty
```

I got an error saying "Qualified name in binding position: Map.empty" when compiling this. I believe that "Map.empty" should belong to the type "Map.Map Int String" that I declare in the newtype.

My question is whether there is a way to alias an empty map correctly.

I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Well a pattern can not contain references to functions, since a pattern contains patterns: a pattern is a composition of variables and constructors.

Comment: Haskell has this pattern feature where you can alias a data value, just like you would alias a type.https://stackoverflow.com/a/49517076/7542147

Comment: @TienHo I am confident that Willem knows about that feature, and encourage you to read his comment again carefully. Also generalize "references to functions" -- it also applies to non-function values.

Comment: "this pattern feature where you can alias a data value" No, you can alias _patterns_. `StoreEnv Map.empty` is not a pattern.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks for that clarification about pattern synonym. So you cannot pattern match against maps like you would do with list then. Is there a way to alias an empty map?

Comment: @TienHo (I suggest you ask that in a separate question but) you can use a _view pattern_ along with `PatternSynonyms`'s ability to give separate definitions for the pattern and the value constructor: `pattern EmptyStore <- StoreEnv (null -> True) where EmptyStore = StoreEnv Map.empty`.

Comment: Thank you so much. That works perfectly!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, actually, this error suggests a theoretically possible extension to the pattern language. A *qualified* name in a pattern could be taken to mean a *value* that needs to be matched with `==`. That would generalize the special rule for numeric literals.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson The question has now been edited. (Personally, I'm OK with the edit -- before that, the question was too vague.) Now, your comment could be an answer.

Comment: @chi cool, thanks for the heads up. I'll write something up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Background

> So you cannot pattern match against maps like you would do with list then.

That's right. `Data.Map.Map` is an [*abstract data type*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#t:Map), meaning that its representation is hidden. In Haskell that means its constructors aren't exported. You can't write code which inspects the [balanced binary search tree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/src/Data.Map.Internal.html#Map) inside the `Map` (and you wouldn't want to anyway) - you have to go through its public interface, using the module's exported functions to create, query and manipulate `Map`s.

Pattern synonyms exist to bridge the gap between ADT programming and the convenient syntax of pattern matching on the left of an equation. You can define some smart patterns as part of your module's API without necessarily coupling the implementation of your ADT to those patterns.

### Your problem

You're getting that error because syntactically the right-hand side of a pattern synonym has to be a pattern, not an expression. A pattern is (usually) the name of a value constructor applied to some *variable binders* - that is, in a definition like

```
getBar (Foo bar baz) = bar
```

the `bar` and `baz` on the left-hand side define variables which will be in scope on the right. They are fresh bindings, not references to any `bar` or `baz` variables which may exist in some outer scope.

So I think that as well as the syntactic mistake (`Map.empty` is not a valid name for a local variable, which is why you're getting that error) you've also made a logical one - you wouldn't have been able to refer to `Map.empty` in that position anyway.

### The fix

As I suggested in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49845591/haskell-qualified-name-in-binding-position-error-with-map-empty?noredirect=1#comment86708642_49845591), you can patch up your code by using an [*explicitly bidirectional pattern synonym*](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#pattern-synonyms). This is a neat feature which lets you give a pattern synonym a different meaning depending on whether it's being used as a pattern (ie in pattern context) or as a value constructor (ie in expression context).

```
pattern EmptyStore <- StoreEnv (Map.null -> True)
    where EmptyStore = StoreEnv Map.empty
```

In the first line I'm defining what `EmptyStore` means when used as a pattern. The `Map.null -> True` syntax is called a *view pattern* - it means "apply the function [`Map.null`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:null) to this piece of the pattern, and match its result with `True`". So `EmptyStore` matches a `StoreEnv` when the `Map` inside the `StoreEnv` is empty.

The second line defines what `EmptyStore` does when used as an expression. It says that the expression `EmptyStore` is a synonym for the expression `StoreEnv Map.empty` - "create an empty `Map` and wrap it in a `StoreEnv`".

### The un-fix

However I submit that a pattern synonym API for `Map` doesn't really make sense. To be usable you should really define a *complete* set of patterns, so that users have a way to deconstruct any type of `Map`. The empty case is easy to handle, because there's only one empty `Map`, but what does it mean to pattern match on a non-empty `Map`? `Map`s aren't meant to be ordered containers - there's no "first-and-rest" like there is with `[]`, so this doesn't make sense:

```
pattern Cons k v rest <- {- what goes here? -}
    where Cons k v rest = insert k v rest
```

You might instead try to define a pattern which matches when a particular key is present in the map:

```
pattern Contains k v <- (lookup k -> Just v)
```

but this is not valid Haskell (`k` is being *referred to*, when it should be being *bound*). Even if you could come up with a clever way to express it, such a set of patterns would necessarily be incomplete because you can't write clauses for every possible key.

In other words, I don't think you should be trying to define pattern synonyms for this datatype. Stick with ordinary functions!

Comment: The last idea, patterns with input and output arguments, is similar to some tricks that can be played with Scala's extractor object / classes. It is indeed a bit weird :)

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer! What I'm doing right now is just to create a wrapper function for Map.empty for my data type

Comment: @TienHo So just use a function, not a pattern synonym: `empty = StoreEnv Map.empty`

Comment: I have one more question. As you mentioned in your post, pattern synonyms are useful for pattern matching on the left of an equation. Then what would be the standard approach to alias a value used on the right hand side? This value is more like a result than a matching pattern I guess. For instance, `get _ = Foo 0`, and I want to provide a convenient name for `Foo 0` such as `Empty`.

Comment: @TienHo The way to do that is as I suggested above. Define a top level constant `fooZero = Foo 0`.